# Do we require a E3 license if we already have a E5 office subscription?

Tags: azure, office365

Do the E5 license covers all features of E3, were there any extra features or compliance settings that are only available in E3?

We are now having a E3 and E5 license on our tenant, to reduce the cost we want to drop one of them, so I want to know which license suffice all the features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E5 will contain all of the features of E3, so you don't need E3 as well as E5

[Compare Microsoft 365 Plans](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-365/compare-microsoft-365-enterprise-plans)